# CRM 4 email router error

Tags: email, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I heed some help. We have na email router for CRM 4 for sending emails. All was fine till this week. It started to send this error and doing nothing.

Error message:

> An error occurred while opening mailbox crmsupport@domainname.ua. Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.EmailException: The remote Microsoft Exchange e-mail server returned the error "(404) Not Found". This user or queue does not have a mailbox. Create a mailbox and try again. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.HttpDavRequest.SubmitXmlCommand(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, String body)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.HttpDavRequest.RetrieveInboxUri()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangeWebDavConnector.OpenMailbox()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.InitExchangeConnector()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.WrapException(Exception e)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.InitExchangeConnector()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.OpenMailbox()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.CrmPollingMailboxProvider.Run()\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.HttpDavRequest.SubmitXmlCommand(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, String body)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.HttpDavRequest.RetrieveInboxUri()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangeWebDavConnector.OpenMailbox()
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Providers.ExchangePollingMailboxProvider.InitExchangeConnector()

Thank you!!!

Comment: How is the email router set up? What kind of email service do you use?